# Elementary geometry problem regarding trapezoid

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

$ABCD$ is a trapezoid with two right angles at $A$ and $B$. The diagonals intersect at $P$. The line through $P$ parallel to the bases intersects sides $AB$ and $CD$ at points $E$ and $F$, respectively.

Prove that $EF$ is the angle bisector of angle $\angle CED$.[image]

If I can prove that the triangles $\Delta BEC$ and $\Delta AED$ are similar, I am done. just one angle apart from the right angle needs to shown to be equal. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Hint: Consider the ratio $BC:AD$ and $BE:AE$. Note that $BE$ is the height of triangle $BPC$ and $AE$ the height of triangle $APD$.

Comment: @user122049 we get that the ratio $BC:AD$ is in proportion to the areas of triangles $BPC$ and $APD$, which are similar. How to proceed from here

Comment: @vidyarthi No, BPC and DPA are similar, so the ratio of their areas is the _square_ of the ratio of their corresponding sides. But you don't need the areas. Just consider their altitudes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triangles $\triangle(BCP)$ and $\triangle(DAP)$ are similar, hence their  heights $EB$ and $EA$  satisfy  $|EB|:|BC|=|EA|:|DA|$.

Answer (score 1):

Say $E =(0,0)$ and we can assume that $P=(1,0)$. Let the line $y=l(x-1)$ cuts y-axis at $A = (0,-l)$ and the line $y=k(x-1)$ cuts y-axis at $B=(0,-k)$. Then we have $$ C = (1-{k\over l},-k)\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\; D = (1-{l\over k},-l)$$

Now the slope of $EC$ is $$ k_1 = {-kl\over l-k}$$ and the slope of $ED$ is $$ k_2 = {-kl\over k-l} = -k_1$$ and we are done.